# Qt animation with double values

Tags: qt, qml

I'm animating the value transition in a gauge

```
CircularGauge {
    onValueChanged: {
        console.info('val' , value)
    }

    Behavior on value {
        RotationAnimation {
            duration: 20000
        }
    }
}
```

But the animation only happens in steps of 1. I did not find a way to make them do smaller steps.

Is there a way?

Comment: try with: `stepSize: 0.1` http://doc.qt.io/QtQuickEnterpriseControls/qml-qtquick-enterprise-controls-circulargauge.html#stepSize-prop

Comment: It draws a tons of ticks, it becomes unreadable.

Comment: Try a normal `PropertyAnimation` (or `NumberAnimation`) instead. The `RotationAnimation` is meant for angles, but you set the value, a normal double, not an angle

Comment: I tried NumberAnimation before. Behaves in precisely the same way