# How to change step size of gauge in Qt

Tags: qt

I think this question is similar to the following question.

[Qt animation with double values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782886/qt-animation-with-double-values)

I am using the following gauge widget.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-extras-gauge.html

I would like to change step size to 0.1.
I set tickmarkStepSize property to 0.1 and scale become 0.1 but gauge step size looks 1.0.
That is even if I change value property every 0.1, gauge changes only every 1.0.

Is there a way how to change gauge step size to 0.1 ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this myself.

It was just a simple mistake.

I set the integer value to value property.

Thank you.